# Computing $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iax}}{1 + e^x} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration

I am attempting to calculate
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iax}}{1 + e^x} dx
\end{equation}
using contour integration around a rectangular region in the upper half plane containing one singularity at $i\pi$. The rectangular region has `height' $2\pi i$. Please see pictured (forgive the crude drawing - if I were feeling less lazy I would have used Tikz)

[image]

I believe the result should be
\begin{equation}\frac{-\pi i}{\sinh{\pi a}}\end{equation}
based on plotting results using this versus the case where the integral is calculated numerically, provided $a$ obeys certain criteria.

I indeed get this result by summing the contributions from
$\int_{\Gamma_1}, \int_{\Gamma_3}$. All that remains is demonstrating that $\int_{\Gamma_2}, \int_{\Gamma_4} = 0$. I have been able to demonstrate $\int_{\Gamma_2} \rightarrow 0$ as $X_2 \rightarrow \infty$ provided $a > 0$.

I have been unable to demonstrate that $\int_{\Gamma_4}\rightarrow0$ as $X_1 \rightarrow \infty$ and was wondering if someone could help?

I imagine there may be a further condition on $a$.
Thanks

Comment: When $x\to-\infty$ the integrand does not go to $0,$ so that direction seems like a problem.

Comment: The integral doesn't converge

Comment: @FShrike. Yes it does. $x\mapsto 1+e^x$ has no real zero and near $\infty$, $e^x$ grows faster than any polynomial.

Comment: Mathematica states that it only converges $-1 < Im[a] < 0$ which makes sense.

Comment: @ DecarbonatedOdes. The question should specify the value of $a$. I made my previous statement about convergence assuming that $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Medo $e^{-100}$ isn't large, it is very very small.

Comment: You can find $\int_0^\infty,$ but not $\int_{-\infty}^\infty.$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews. You are right. I was thinking of $e^{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes This is what I was after - I was looking for a criteria on $a$ such that the result was correct. Essentially by subtracting an infinitesimal imaginary part from $a$ the integral converges and the result is $\frac{-\pi i}{\sinh(\pi (a - i\delta))}$

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda long for a comment... For respectful friends.

...

$\Gamma_4: z=-R+iy$, $y:2\pi\rightarrow 0$.

$$\int_{\Gamma_4}\frac{e^{iaz}}{e^z+1}dz=\int_{2\pi}^0\frac{e^{-iaR}e^{-ay}}{e^{-R}e^{iy}+1}idy\approx -ie^{-iaR}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-ay}dy=i\frac{e^{-iaR}}{a}(1-e^{-2\pi a})$$
It is not going to zero. Sorry.
But if we choose $R=\frac{2\pi N}{a}$ where $N$ is integer, it has the value $\frac{i}{a}(1-e^{-2\pi a})$. Nonsense.

Comment: This should be a comment, I think

Comment: I will add WA outputs. Wait...